# ArcGIS UWP Offline Map

Tags: .net, arcgis-runtime

How to download the ArcGIS map in windows UWP applications?
I am new to using this SDK , And need to Implement the map working in offline .Please give me a suggestion or any Materiel 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a few resources you can refer to:

- [Download a preplanned map area sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/tree/master/src/UWP/ArcGISRuntime.UWP.Viewer/Samples/Map/DownloadPreplannedMap)
- [Generate offline map sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/tree/master/src/UWP/ArcGISRuntime.UWP.Viewer/Samples/Map/GenerateOfflineMap)
- [Generate offline map with overrides sample](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-dotnet/tree/master/src/UWP/ArcGISRuntime.UWP.Viewer/Samples/Map/GenerateOfflineMap) - this is the same as above, but demonstrates more parameters/options.

For more information about the preplanned and on-demand(generate) workflows, see [Work with offline maps](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/guide/work-with-offline-maps.htm) in the doc.

The [demos repo](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-demos-dotnet) is a great place to look for more complicated demos. There's currently an open PR with an offline workflow demo built in UWP.

If you'd like to explore the capabilities of the SDK without building the samples yourself, you can find the sample viewer in the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MTP5013343H). That is the WPF sample viewer, but the samples are the same as what you'll find in the UWP sample viewer.

Comment: I had gone through what you have mentioned but still not getting properly . The document is not that much clear about the offline explanation

Comment: @NaveenDvg If you can share more about what you're trying to accomplish and what you're having problems with specifically, I can try to find better resources or work on enhancing our documentation and samples. There are a lot of moving parts (e.g. web map configuration, layer configuration, ArcGIS Online configuration) needed to get offline maps working, so I'd appreciate any info you can share to identify the problem.